# iPhone reports large storage On My Phone, but I can't find that usage

Tags: iphone, ios, disk-space

[iPhone 11 128GB, running iOS 13.6]

In Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage, **On My Phone** reports there is 1.16GB on my iPhone. However, if I tap into that section and review all the files there, I see at most 23MB worth of data when I add everything up. Restarting the phone doesn't change the numbers.

Is there some other place I should look to find these "large files?" Is there a known issue of reporting incorrect file sizes? Something else?

Comment: My iPhone says xx of yy Used.  What are the xx and yy on your phone?

Comment: How many photos on your phone?

Comment: Could it be some files from iCloud Drive? To me it seems that all files, which don't have their app on the device won't show up, but consume space.

Comment: @awado Unlikely - if I go into Apple ID -> iCloud -> Manage Storage -> iCloud Drive, that number is 418KB. My total iCloud Storage usage is ~2.7GB (which is mostly from Messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These numbers do not add up on iOS 13.6 and lower in my experience. Apple has started patching the system to make these more accurate on iOS 13.6.1

[image]

Be sure you check other storage in addition to the on my device portion after a clean power down and connect to power. I think the metadata collection and snapshot freeing run better when connected to power and that there is a gradual cleanup so the numbers are shifting daily in my experience for both my iPhone and iPad but they are aligning much better than before.

Comment: My **On My Phone** storage now reports 4KB under 13.6.1. Bug apparently fixed!

Answer (score 1):

If the airdrop transfer of a large file failed, iOS may delete it and put it in "recently deleted files" of Files app. You may check this folder.

picture 1(1/3)

[image: pic1]

picture 2(2/3)

[image: pic2]

picture 3(3/3)

[image: pic3]

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on an unused iPhone. After factory resetting, this screen shows 671 MB used. I have not activated iCloud, TouchID or such. I guess this is system related user data, which is otherwise nowhere accessible. (Caches, fonts, location tracking and temporary data etc.)

Comment: If so, that sure is a lot of "temporary data" for no usage!

Comment: OK I looked at this setting on my work iPhone (which I use very little other than Phone & Messages. **On My Phone** is only **4KB** there! Very strange.

Answer (score -1):

Under the part that says xx of yy used is a color scale that shows you what makes up the used portion of memory. That should tell you what is using over a GB of data.  It is probably your photos.

Comment: No, I am specifically talking about the **On My Phone** line item, which is distinct from **Photos**